# One class for each layout (new page)?

Tags: android, layout, shortcut

I wast just wondering if the standard practice is to create an activity/fragment class for each layout file (new page). 
Example:

**MainActivity.java**

```
onCreate(){
    setContentView(R.layout.**start_page**)
}
```

And than when the user clicks a button in the action bar (or some other button on the screen):

```
onOptionItemSelected() {
    switch XX -> case XX: setContentView(R.layout.**next_page**) 
}
```

So could i do the above instead of launching a new activity.java (that contains a new layout.xml) with an intent, or inflating the view with a fragment.java (that also contains a new layout.xml).

I can see that the up/back navigation wouldn't work with the above code, but is that the only reason why you basically have to create two files (.java & .xml) for each new page in your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you could do it technically but beware that if you already create an instance of view lets say Button and you change the layout button will be null because button is not located in your View and also it will take time to render again the layout. So it is a best practice to start a new activity or just create a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, but every view will be on the given Activity, and the event handlers would be in the same class, which isn't really modular. It could get extremely bloated and you'll have a 2000 line superclass because it handles every single button click in arbitrary functions (or even worse, in a single onClick function).